# getting a variable from one class to another class

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

i would like to get a variable from one of my classes to the another class.
the variable that i want to use is profile which is on line 129. i would like to use this variable outside of this class and into the class AddJob() down at the bottom of my code. it would much appreciated if anyone could possibly just give me a solution as i have been trying to get this to work for days.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

import webbrowser
import re

Background = ("WHITE")
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 9)
HOME_FONT = ("Times", 15, "bold")
EMAIL_FONT = ("times", 9)


def DataBase():
    with sqlite3.connect("UserInfo.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,

    username STRING,
    password STRING, 
    firstname STRING, 
    surname STRING,
    email STRING);
    ''')

    cursor.execute ('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jobs(
    jobID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    userID
    jobtitle STRING,
    jobdescript STRING);
    ''')



class MsgBox(tkinter.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, title = "", message = ""):
        tkinter.Toplevel.__init__(self)

        self.title(title)

        self.label = tkinter.Label(self, text = message)
        self.label['bg'] = 'white'
        self.label.pack(ipadx = 10, ipady = 10, fill = 'both', expand = True)

        self.button = tkinter.Button(self, text = "OK")
        self.button['command'] = self.destroy
        self.button.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10, ipadx = 20, side = 'right')


class JobApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames = {}


        #this is where you add a page to the program so you can add different functions
        for F in (LoginPage, SignUp, HomePage, MenuPage, MapPage, ProfilePage, SettingsPage, JobsPage, AddJob):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(LoginPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    DataBase()


class LoginPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.Logo = PhotoImage(file = "Logo.gif")

        def Log_in():

            with sqlite3.connect("UserInfo.db") as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()


            user = (self.UserEntry.get())
            Pass = (self.PassEntry.get())

            if user == "" or Pass == "":
                msg = MsgBox("", "Make sure to fill all the boxes\nPlease try again")
                msg.label['font'] = 'Verdana 10'
                msg.button['text'] = 'Close'
                msg.button.pack(expand = True)

            else:

                dictionary = {}
                cursor.execute("SELECT username, password FROM users")
                for pword in cursor.fetchall():
                    (key ,val) = tuple(pword)
                    dictionary[str(key)] = val



                if user in dictionary:
                    if dictionary[user] == Pass:

                        sql = '''SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username = ?'''
                        cursor.execute(sql, (user,))

                        profile = cursor.fetchall()

                        controller.show_frame(HomePage)
                        self.UserEntry.delete(0, 'end')
                        self.PassEntry.delete(0, 'end')

                    else:
                        messagebox.showinfo("", "Enter the correct password")
                        self.PassEntry.delete(0, 'end')

        self.logo = tk.Label(self, image = self.Logo)

        self.User = tk.Label(self, text = "User Name:").place(x = 72, y = 130)
        self.Pass = tk.Label(self, text = "Password:").place(x = 80, y = 155)

        self.UserEntry = Entry(self)

        self.PassEntry = Entry(self, show = '*')

        self.login = ttk.Button(self, text = "Login", command = Log_in)
        self.signup = ttk.Button(self, text = "Create account",
                                 command = lambda:controller.show_frame(SignUp))

        self.UserEntry.place(width = 100, height = 20, x = 140, y = 130)
        self.PassEntry.place(width = 100, height = 20, x = 140, y = 155)
        self.login.place(x = 80, y = 180)
        self.signup.place(x = 160, y = 180)
        self.logo.place(x = 110, y = 20)


class SignUp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)




        def Save_info():

            DataBase()

            with sqlite3.connect("UserInfo.db") as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()

            FnameEntry = self.FnameEntry.get()
            SnameEntry = self.SnameEntry.get()
            EmailEntry = self.EmailEntry.get()
            UserNameEntry = self.UserNameEntry.get()
            PassWordEntry = self.PassWordEntry.get()
            RenterPasswordEntry = self.RenterPasswordEntry.get()

            check = []
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                check.append(row)
            print (check)


            if not re.match(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", EmailEntry):
                messagebox.showinfo("ERROR", "the email that you entered was not valid\nPlease try again")

            if len(FnameEntry) == 0 or len(SnameEntry) == 0 or len(EmailEntry) == 0 or len(UserNameEntry) == 0 or len(PassWordEntry) == 0 or len(RenterPasswordEntry) == 0:
                messagebox.showinfo("No fill", "You didn't fill all the fields")
            else:
                if len(UserNameEntry) < 6:
                    messagebox.showinfo("Not long enough", "your username wasn't long enough\nPlease try again")
                else:
                    if len(PassWordEntry) < 6:
                        messagebox.showinfo("Not long enough", "Your password wasn't long enough\nPlease try again")
                    else:
                        if RenterPasswordEntry != PassWordEntry:
                            messagebox.showinfo("pass word match up", "Your passwords didn't seem to match up\nPlease try again")
                        else:
                            if UserNameEntry in check:
                                messagebox.showinfo("", "The user name that you entered already exsists\nPlease enter a different one")
                                self.UserNameEntry.delete(0, 'end')
                                self.PassWordEntry.delete(0, 'end')
                                self.RenterPasswordEntry.delete(0, 'end')
                            else:
                                YesNo = messagebox.askokcancel("Continue", "would you like to go back to the login page")
                                if YesNo == True:

                                    self.FnameEntry.delete(0, 'end')
                                    self.SnameEntry.delete(0, 'end')
                                    self.EmailEntry.delete(0, 'end')
                                    self.UserNameEntry.delete(0, 'end')
                                    self.PassWordEntry.delete(0, 'end')
                                    self.RenterPasswordEntry.delete(0, 'end')



                                    cursor.execute("""
                                    INSERT INTO users (username,password,firstname,surname,email)
                                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                                    """, (UserNameEntry, PassWordEntry, FnameEntry, SnameEntry, EmailEntry))
                                    db.commit()

                                    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
                                    print(cursor.fetchall())                                            

                                    controller.show_frame(LoginPage)

        self.x = ttk.Label(self, text = "fill in the information to create an account.\n\nBoxes with * next to them must be filled in.\nYour Username must be longer than 6 characters.\nYour password must be longer than 6 characters.\n", font = LARGE_FONT).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        self.Fname = ttk.Label(self, text = "First Name *:", font = LARGE_FONT).grid(row = 1, sticky = "e")
        self.Sname = ttk.Label(self, text = "Surname *:", font = LARGE_FONT).grid(row = 2, sticky = "e")
        self.Email = ttk.Label(self, text = "Email Address *:", font = LARGE_FONT).grid(row = 3, sticky = "e")
        self.UserName = ttk.Label(self, text = "User name *:", font = LARGE_FONT).grid(row = 4, sticky = "e")
        self.PassWord = ttk.Label(self, text = "Password *:", font = LARGE_FONT).grid(row = 5, sticky = "e")
        self.ReneterPassword = ttk.Label(self, text = "Confirm password *:", font = LARGE_FONT).grid(row = 6, sticky = "e")

        self.blank = ttk.Label(self, text = "").grid(row = 8)
        Continue = ttk.Button(self, text = "Continue",
                              command = Save_info).grid(row = 9, rowspan = 2, stick = "e")
        Cancel = ttk.Button(self , text = "Cancel",
                            command= lambda:controller.show_frame(LoginPage)).grid(row = 9, column = 1, stick = "w")

        self.FnameEntry = Entry(self)
        self.SnameEntry = Entry(self)
        self.EmailEntry = Entry(self)
        self.UserNameEntry = Entry(self)
        self.PassWordEntry = Entry(self)
        self.RenterPasswordEntry = Entry(self)

        self.FnameEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = "w")
        self.SnameEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = "w")
        self.EmailEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = "w")
        self.UserNameEntry.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = "w")
        self.PassWordEntry.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = "w")
        self.RenterPasswordEntry.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = "w")


class HomePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        def on_entry_click(event):
            if self.postcode.get() == 'Postcode':
                self.postcode.delete(0, "end")
                self.postcode.insert(0, '')
                self.postcode.config(fg = 'black')

        def on_focusout(event):
            if self.postcode.get() == '':
                self.postcode.delete(0, "end")
                self.postcode.insert(0, 'Postcode')
                self.postcode.config(fg = 'grey')

        def on_entry_click2(event):
            if self.searchjob.get() == 'Enter a job you want to search for..':
                self.searchjob.delete(0, "end")
                self.searchjob.insert(0, '')
                self.searchjob.config(fg = 'black')

        def on_focusout2(event):
            if self.searchjob.get() == '':
                self.searchjob.delete(0, "end")
                self.searchjob.insert(0, 'Enter a job you want to search for..')

                self.searchjob.config(fg = 'grey')

        Homepagecanvas = Canvas(self, width = 320, height = 568)
        Homepagecanvas.pack()

        TopBarHome = Homepagecanvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 320, 50, fill = 'light grey')
        Home = Homepagecanvas.create_text((80, 25), text = "Home", font = HOME_FONT)

        MenuButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Menu",
                            command = lambda:controller.show_frame(MenuPage)).place(height = 40, width = 40, x = 5, y = 5)

        self.postcode = Entry(self)
        self.searchjob = Entry(self)

        self.postcode.insert(0, 'Postcode')
        self.postcode.bind('<FocusIn>', on_entry_click)
        self.postcode.bind('<FocusOut>', on_focusout)
        self.postcode.config(fg = 'grey')
        self.postcode.place(width = 60, height = 30, x = 10, y = 60)

        self.searchjob.insert(0, 'Enter a job you want to search for..')
        self.searchjob.bind('<FocusIn>', on_entry_click2)
        self.searchjob.bind('<FocusOut>', on_focusout2)
        self.searchjob.config(fg = 'grey')
        self.searchjob.place(width = 220, height = 30, x = 80, y = 60)

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self)
        scrollbar.place(width = 10, height =
                        450, x = 10, y = 100)

        Joblist = Listbox(self, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
        for line in range(100):
            Joblist.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))

        Joblist.place(height = 450, width = 280, x = 25, y = 100)
        scrollbar.config(command = Joblist.yview)


class MenuPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        Homepagecanvas = Canvas(self, width = 320, height = 568)
        Homepagecanvas.pack()

        TopBarHome = Homepagecanvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 320, 50, fill = 'light grey')
        Home = Homepagecanvas.create_text((40, 15), text = "Menu", font = HOME_FONT)
        Home = Homepagecanvas.create_text((160, 35), text = "here you can navigate to other pages in the application")

        Home = tk.Button(self,
                         text = "Home Page",
                         relief = GROOVE,
                         command = lambda:controller.show_frame(HomePage)).place(width = 100, height = 30, x = 10, y = 60)

        Map = tk.Button(self,
                        text = "Map",
                        relief = GROOVE,
                        command = lambda:controller.show_frame(MapPage)).place(width = 100, height = 30, x = 10, y = 90)

        Profile = tk.Button(self,
                            text = "Profile",
                            relief = GROOVE,
                            command = lambda:controller.show_frame(ProfilePage)).place(width = 100, height = 30, x = 10, y = 120)

        Settings = tk.Button(self,
                            text = "Settings",
                            relief = GROOVE,
                            command = lambda:controller.show_frame(SettingsPage)).place(width = 100, height = 30, x = 10, y = 150)

        Jobs = tk.Button(self,
                            text = "Jobs",
                            relief = GROOVE,
                            command = lambda:controller.show_frame(JobsPage)).place(width = 100, height = 30, x = 10, y = 180)



class MapPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        MapPageCanvas = Canvas(self, width = 320, height = 568)
        MapPageCanvas.pack()

        TopBar = MapPageCanvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 320, 50,
                                                fill = 'light grey')
        Home = MapPageCanvas.create_text((80, 25),
                                         text = "Map",
                                         font = HOME_FONT)

        MenuButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Menu",
                            command = lambda:controller.show_frame(MenuPage)).place(height = 40, width = 40, x = 5, y = 5)


class ProfilePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        def on_entry_click(event):
            if self.postcode.get() == 'Postcode':
                self.postcode.delete(0, "end")
                self.postcode.insert(0, '')
                self.postcode.config(fg = 'black')

        def on_focusout(event):
            if self.postcode.get() == '':
                self.postcode.delete(0, "end")
                self.postcode.insert(0, 'Postcode')
                self.postcode.config(fg = 'grey')

        ProfilePageCanvas = Canvas(self, width = 320, height = 568)
        ProfilePageCanvas.pack()

        TopBar = ProfilePageCanvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 320, 50,
                                                    fill = 'light grey')
        Profile = ProfilePageCanvas.create_text((80, 25), text = "Profile",
                                                font = HOME_FONT)

        MenuButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Menu",
                            command = lambda:controller.show_frame(MenuPage)).place(height = 40, width = 40, x = 5, y = 5)

        def logout():
            result = messagebox.askokcancel("Logout", "would you like to logout")
            if result == True:
                controller.show_frame(LoginPage)

        Logout = ttk.Button(self, text = "Logout",
                            command = logout).place(width = 60, height = 40, x = 255 , y = 5)


class SettingsPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        MapPageCanvas = Canvas(self, width = 320, height = 568)
        MapPageCanvas.pack()

        TopBar = MapPageCanvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 320, 50,
                                                fill = 'light grey')
        Home = MapPageCanvas.create_text((90, 25),
                                         text = "Settings",
                                         font = HOME_FONT)

        MenuButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Menu",
                            command = lambda:controller.show_frame(MenuPage)
                            ).place(height = 40, width = 40, x = 5, y = 5)

        def BG():
            app.configure(background = Background)

        def Toggle():

            if DarkTheme.config('relief')[-1] == 'flat':
                DarkTheme.config(relief = "sunken", bg = 'grey')
            else:
                DarkTheme.config(relief = "flat", bg = 'white')

            Background = "DARK GRAY"

            BG()

        DarkTheme = tk.Button(self,
                              bg = 'white',
                              highlightbackground = 'black',
                              text = "Dark Theme",
                              pady = 5, padx = 5,
                              relief = "flat",
                              command = Toggle)
        DarkTheme.place(x = 5, y = 60)


class JobsPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        MapPageCanvas = Canvas(self, width = 320, height = 568)
        MapPageCanvas.pack()

        TopBar = MapPageCanvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 320, 50,
                                                fill = 'light grey')
        Home = MapPageCanvas.create_text((80, 25),
                                         text = "Jobs",
                                         font = HOME_FONT)

        MenuButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Menu",
                            command = lambda:controller.show_frame(MenuPage)).place(height = 40, width = 40, x = 5, y = 5)

        addjob = ttk.Button(self, text = "Add Job",
                            command = lambda:controller.show_frame(AddJob)).place(height = 40, width = 60, x = 255, y = 5)







class AddJob(tk.Frame, LoginPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        def dbAddJob():


            JobT = self.Jt.get("1.0", 'end').rstrip('\n')
            JobD = self.Jd.get("1.0", 'end').rstrip('\n')

            with sqlite3.connect("UserInfo.db") as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()

            if JobT == "" or JobD == "":
                messagebox.showinfo("Invalid","please fill in the boxes or cancel") 
            else:
                aj = messagebox.askokcancel("Continue", "Job added click ok to continue\nor cancel or change what you have added")
                if aj == True:
                    cursor.execute("""
                    INSERT INTO jobs (jobtitle, jobdescript)
                    VALUES (?, ?)
                    """, (JobT, JobD))
                    db.commit()
                    self.Jt.delete('1.0', END)
                    self.Jd.delete('1.0', END)

                    controller.show_frame(JobsPage)

            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM jobs")
            print(cursor.fetchall())

        MapPageCanvas = Canvas(self, width = 320, height = 568)
        MapPageCanvas.pack()

        TopBar = MapPageCanvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 320, 50,
                                                fill = 'light grey')
        Home = MapPageCanvas.create_text((100, 25),
                                         text = "Add a Job",
                                         font = HOME_FONT)

        MenuButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Back",
                            command = lambda:controller.show_frame(JobsPage)).place(height = 40, width = 40, x = 5, y = 5)

        self.Addjobbutton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Add",
                                 command = dbAddJob).place(width = 60, height = 30, x = 90, y = 520)

        self.Cancel = ttk.Button(self, text = "cancel",
                                command = lambda:controller.show_frame(JobsPage)).place(width = 60, height = 30, x = 170, y = 520)

        self.Jt = ScrolledText(self)
        self.Jd = ScrolledText(self)

        self.Jt.place(height = 30, width = 310, x = 5, y = 60)
        self.Jd.place(height = 400, width = 310, x = 5, y = 100)




app = JobApp()
app.geometry('320x568')
app.resizable(0,0)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be putting all your code into the question.  Please edit the question and leave only the relevant parts.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **minimal** [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make it a global variable such as ?

```
sound = None

class Cat(object):
     global sound

     """
     All your code
     """

     sound = "meow"
```

Now if you use 'global sound' you can acces the global variable from everywhere, now sound returns:

```
>>> sound
'meow'
```

This way you can acces a variable from without a class or function.